# Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php

    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    $db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'bfp_drrm');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM initial";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

?>
```

The result should be the data table of the database. This is the warning/error:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No connection could be
> made because the target machine actively refused it in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\BFP_READY_F\Regional\realtime.php:273 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\BFP_READY_F\Regional\realtime.php(273):
> mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '') #1 {main} thrown in.."

Comment: Have you tried using a suitable password?

Comment: may i know how? @ProfessorAbronsius

Comment: [mysqli_connect](https://www.php.net/function.mysqli-connect) - essentially though it is like this: `$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');`

Comment: how to make the suitable password? @ProfessorAbronsius

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it in" means **no connection could be made** to the destination server at all. Even before checking passwords or anything. It's rather a firewall issue.

Comment: @futurecomscientist do you have mysql *installed* on your computer?